# CMD command to get the list of only files not folders

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, dir

I have around 30K files under various subfolders. I need the cmd command to print the list of all the 30K files and only the filenames not the folders.

Comment: If you have 2 folders _folder00_ and _folder01_ and under _folder00_ there are _file00.txt_ and _file01.txt_  and under _folder01_ there is _file00.txt_ what would the expected output be? (i'm interested about the folders in file names).

Comment: file00.txt,file01.txt,file00.txt

Comment: Thank you, but you already have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** to include file redirection

```dos
>"x:\targetFile.txt" (for /r %a in ("x:\startFolder\*") do @echo %~nxa)
```

Just a recursive enumeration of the files. For each file found echo to console the name and extension of the file.

Comment: i want to print the output to a text file

Comment: Then simply redirect the command output: add this at the end of the command `>>file.txt`.

Comment: @CristiFati yes i did the same but the file is getting overwritten and only has the last value

Comment: Didn't you use `>` instead of `>>`?

Comment: @CristiFati, look at the parenthesis. It is redirecting the full output of the `for` command, not the output of each of the `echo` commands.

Comment: @MC ND: Yes, it's much better this way, than appending each `echo` output. But my previous question was for Maverick (forgot to specify that).

Comment: I found this working really fast for me.
Will store all file paths in all subdirectories to the file: "dir /B /S /A-D > fileList.txt" (Works on windows only though)

Comment: @Quintonn Yes, it is fastest, but the request is not to include paths, only file names